# How to make a vertical organizational chart with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I'm trying to create a vertical organizational chart with `Tikz` and the `trees` library. However, the lines connecting the different elements between them are not displayed as I would like.

Indeed, I want to obtain a "vertical" diagram, so I use `below = ... of ...` to position the elements one below the other, but the connecting lines are displayed in front of the text boxes and not behind, what I don't want, as shown in the following image:

[image]

Also, with the `rounded corners` option, I get this :
[image]
when I think it would have been more logical to get something like this : [image]

What can be done about it?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, trees}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        childStyle/.style={text width=3cm},
        level 1/.style={childStyle, sibling distance=35mm, nodes={fill=red!50}},
        level 2/.style={nodes={fill=red!25}},
    ]
\node[fill=red!75]{Blah blah blah}[edge from parent fork down, rounded corners=6pt]
child{node (A) {Blah blah blah}
        child {node[below = 5mm of A] (A1) {Blah blah blah}}
        child {node[below = 5mm of A1] (A2) {Blah blah}}
        child {node[below = 5mm of A2] (A3) {Blah blah blah}}
        child {node[below = 5mm of A3] (A4) {Blah}}
    }
child{node (B) {Blah blah}
        child {node[below = 5mm of B] (B1) {Blah blah}}
        child {node[below = 5mm of B1] (B2) {Blah blah blah blah blah blah}}
    }
child{node (C) {Blah blah blah}
        child {node[below = 5mm of C] (C1) {Blah blah}}
        child {node[below = 5mm of C1] (C2) {Blah blah}}
        child {node[below = 5mm of C2] (C3) {Blah blah blah}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `forest` package is simple:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes
    text width=32mm,
    outer sep=0pt,
if level=0{fill=red!50}{rounded corners, fill=red!20},
if level=1{fill=red!50}{},
% tree
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
% edges 
    forked edge,
    s sep = 2mm,
    l sep = 4mm,
 fork sep = 2mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
     edge = {semithick, rounded corners=3pt},
            }
[Blah blah blah, name=root
    [Blah blah blah
        [Blah blah blah 
            [Blah blah 
                [Blah blah blah
                    [Blah]
        ]   ]   ]  
    ]
    [Blah blah blah, name=middle, no edge
        [Blah blah blah 
            [Blah blah blah blah blah blah]
        ]   
    ]
    [Blah blah blah 
        [Blah blah 
            [Blah blah 
                [Blah blah blah]
        ]   ]
    ]
]
\draw[semithick]    (root) -- (middle);
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think OP wants the connecting lines in front of the cells.

Comment: @SandyG, indeed. Very unusual. For this demand I need more time ...

Comment: @Zarko Thank you for your answer. The use of this package is very interesting. I expressed myself badly in my question, I want the connection lines to be behind the text boxes and not in front of them. My apologies, I have edited my question accordingly. Your answer using the `forest` package gives me the desired result.

Comment: @Bastien, OK, I will delete Addendum. It is not needed anymore.